# grunt-contrib-clean to remove all folders/files except for one folder and its contents

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

How would you negate the cleaning of a particular folder using grunt-contrib-clean.  Negating the match doesn't appear to work.

```
clean: {
    plugins: [ 
        'app/plugins/myplugin',
        '!app/plugins/myplugin/assets'
    ]
}
```

I've tried a couple different negation patterns, such as:

```
'!app/plugins/myplugin/assets'
'!app/plugins/myplugin/assets/**'
```

as well as, reversing the positions in the array in case that mattered.  Can't seem to hold onto the assets folder/contents on clean.  The assets folder contains jQuery, AngularJS, and built Bootstrap (SASS), which I don't want to have to keep copying/building, seems a waste of time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I quickly set up a folder structure like you're referencing and tried the following, that works for me:

```
clean: {
    options: {
        'no-write': true
    },
    plugins: ['app/plugins/myplugin/**/*', '!app/plugins/myplugin/assets/**']
}
```

The first wildcard selects all files inside the myplugin folder and all subfolders (but not the directory `myplugin` itself!), while the negation deselects the whole assets directory including all subfolders and files.

You should remove the options field for real testing, as `no-write: true` is only simulating a clean but doesn't actually delete files.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks that works great. I appreciate the explanation. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the ability to blow away all of bower_components except for require.js. Here is how I did it in my gruntFile:

```
            /* all bower components except require */
            applicationDistHome + '/bower_components/**/*',
            '!' + applicationDistHome + '/bower_components/requirejs/**',
            applicationDistHome + '/bower_components/requirejs/*',
            '!' + applicationDistHome + '/bower_components/requirejs/require.js',
```